# (Dual Booting) How Can I Make Windows Ignore Ubuntu EFI Partition

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have two hard drives in my computer, hard drive 1 is Windows and hard drive 2 is Ubuntu. I know some people recommend only using one EFI, but I prefer having my operating systems (and therefore the EFI as well) separated physically like this.

Recently a Windows update destroyed my entire Windows install, so I've had to re-install via USB.
The problem is that even with a seperate fat32 EFI created on hard drive 1 specifically for Windows, Windows installs to the hard drive I've specified for it, but it uses the EFI on the other hard drive (my Ubuntu one). This makes it and Ubuntu share the same EFI and then I get a message every boot into my Ubuntu that says the EFI is almost full (and by almost it means a few KB).

How can I force Windows to use the EFI I've created specifically for it on hard drive 1, and prevent it from writing to the EFI on my Ubuntu hard drive 2?

Comment: You can physically disconnect the Ubuntu drive, but may have to use efibootmgr to recreate the Ubuntu entry in UEFI as it forgets disconnected drive. Or reinstall grub-efi-amd64. You probably can also just in UEFI change drive's settings to disabled. You then have logically disconnected it.

Answer (score 0):

I also dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows using two separate hard drives.

The way I got everything to work properly was to install Windows without the Ubuntu drive pyhsically connected to the computer.  After Windows is installed, you can install Ubuntu onto just the one drive with both connected since Ubuntu lets you choose what disks to modify.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KUPOinyourWINDOW Oh man.  Sorry to hear that.  This is the only way I know how to do it unfortunately.  I hope someone else can help you figure this out :)

Comment: I don't want to change EFI on previous Windows Partition /sda1. I'm installing ubunt in a usb storage /sdb and I want to select in bios the bootable medium when using Linux. Should I change in "Installation Type" the EFI partition from "Use as: EFI System Partition" to "do not use the partition"? If I mark all /sda partitions as "do not use.." will the installer change something in /sda? Should I create a new EFI partition in /sdb for ubuntu? Thanks